# Weighted Average Grade Calculation - hash iteration with nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm having trouble calculating a weighted ratio in Ruby and Rails.  As an illustrative scenario, say we have a a weighted average grade calculation for a class in school.  I have tests "a", "b" and "c" which have class-level weighting of 0.25, 0.50, and 0.25, respectively.  Jenny's scores are 0.95, 0.85 and nil, respectively where she was exempt for the last test.  When a student is exempt from the test, the weighting should not count against them.  Consider that jenny_grade_scores below is an ActiveRecord Object and TEST_WEIGHTS is a constant in the model.

```
jenny_grade_scores = { "test_a" => 0.95, "test_b" => 0.85, "test_c" => nil }

TEST_WEIGHTS = { "test_a_weight" => 0.25, "test_b_weight" => 0.50, "test_c_weight" => 0.25 }
```

What's a more efficient way to calculate the weighted score for this than using:

```
jenny_test_weights = TEST_WEIGHTS #initialize a student test weight variable and adjust if test score is nil
jenny_test_weights["test_a_weight"] = 0.0 if jenny_grade_scores["test_a"].nil?
jenny_test_weights["test_b_weight"] = 0.0 if jenny_grade_scores["test_b"].nil?
jenny_test_weights["test_c_weight"] = 0.0 if jenny_grade_scores["test_c"].nil?


numerator = (jenny_grade_scores["test_a"] * jenny_test_weights["test_a_weight"] +jenny_grade_scores["test_b"] * jenny_test_weights["test_b_weight"] + jenny_grade_scores["test_c"] * jenny_test_weights["test_c_weight"]) 

denominator = (jenny_test_weights["test_a_weight"] + jenny_test_weights["test_b_weight"] + jenny_test_weights["test_c_weight"])

final_score = numerator / denominator
```

In this example, the result should be 0.88333333

Comment: 0.6625 is the numerator and 0.75 is denominator = .883333

Comment: No denominator is 1 (= 0.25 + 0.5 + 0.25)

Comment: jenny's grade score for test c is nil so denominator for jenny should be 0.75.  See jenny_test_weights["test_c_weight"] = 0.0 if jenny_grade_scores["test_c"].nil?

Comment: If you are thinking of typical mathematical weighted averages; the denominator is a simple sum of the weights, its independent of the grades.

Comment: I agree the sum of the weights would be 1 in a typical weighted average, however, the original question notes that we don't want to penalize the student when, in the example, a student is exempt from, has opted out, or not yet taken a test.  The denominator of the calculation needs to be dynamic based on the grades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about converting all test scores to float?

```
>> jenny_grade_scores.inject({}) { |hash, array| hash[array[0]] = array[1].to_f; hash }           
=> {"test_a"=>0.95, "test_b"=>0.85, "test_c"=>0.0}
```

If you don't mind refactoring your code, consider the following:

```
WEIGHTS = { a: 0.25, b: 0.5, c: 0.25 }

grades = { a: 0.95, b: 0.85 , c: nil }

SUM_OF_WEIGHTS = WEIGHTS.inject(0) do |sum, (test, weight)|
  sum += grades[test].nil? ? 0 : weight
end # => 0.75

weighted_score = grades.inject(0) do |w, (test, score)|
  w += (score.to_f * WEIGHTS[test])
end # => 0.6625

final_score = weighted_score / SUM_OF_WEIGHTS # => 0.8833333333333333
```

Footnotes:

1. Renaming the test keys to same key in all related hashes can simplify the problem.
2. `nil` when converted to float becomes 0.0.
3. `inject` & `reduce` can do summation or similar collection related operation elegantly. More over its more idiomatic Ruby, try & learn them if you are not familiar with it.
4. Updated for non-penalized weight calculation.

Comment: You footnotes are very well taken and I am certainly open to refactoring my ugly code - thank you.  Inject and reduce are both new to me, so I have some reading to do.  Is there a better way to handle the denominator as mentioned in my response to your comment to my question?

Comment: Sure, I have just updated with the non-penalized weight calculation.

Comment: :), sure! Try learning `inject` and `reduce`; they can make your code very expressive and powerful!